# Create a copy of Redshift production with limited # records in each table

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a production Redshift cluster with a significant amount of data on it. I would like to create a 'dummy' copy of the cluster that I can use for ad-hoc development and testing of various data pipelines. The copy would have all the schemas/tables of production, but only a small subset of the records in each table (say, limited to 10,000 rows per table).

What would be a good way to create such a copy, and refresh it on a regular basis (in case production schemas change)? Is there a way to create a snapshot of a cluster with limits on each table?

So far my thinking is to create a new cluster and use some of the admin views as defined [here](https://github.com/awslabs/amazon-redshift-utils/tree/master/src/AdminViews) to automatically get the DDL of schemas/tables etc. and write scripts that generate UNLOAD statements (with limits on number of records) for each table. I can then use these to populate my dev cluster. However I feel there must be a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

I presume your basic goal is **cost-saving**. This needs to be balanced against **administrative effort** (how expensive is your time?).

It might be cheaper to **produce a full-copy** (restore from backup) of the cluster but **turn it off at night/weekends to save money**. If you automate the restoration process you could even schedule it to start before you come into work.

That way, you'll have a complete replica of the production system with effectively **zero administration overhead** (once you write a couple of scripts to create/delete the cluster) and you can **save 75% of the costs** (40 out of 168 hours per week). Plus, each time you create a new cluster it contains the latest data from the snapshot, so there is no need to keep them "in sync".

The simplest solutions are often the best.

Comment: Good thought @johnrotenstein, I have similar situation, where I could try this.

Comment: We have a similar situation were we have something like 100 nodes, so the process of restoring a snapshot is quite heavy, any other idea ?

Comment: @lelabo_m It would be better for you to ask a new Question. Please include information about why you need 100 nodes — presumably it is due to the amount of data. Using Amazon Redshift Spectrum might be an option to reduce the amount of data you are loading into Redshift.